# How to Produce an Abbreviated TOC with Ancillary Items Suppressed

Tags: table-of-contents, luatex, shorttoc

One of the documents I am working on has hundreds of section entries and an even greater number of subsection entries in the TOC.

I am considering producing a version of the document that contains an abbreviated version of the TOC---where the subsections in appearing the full version are suppressed.

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

Some words.
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{\bf 1.} The main part of the TOC entries for 1.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Ancillary TOC entries for \textbf{1.}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Ancillary TOC entries for \textbf{1.}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Ancillary TOC entries for \textbf{1.}}

\newpage
Some more words.
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{\bf 2.} The main part of the TOC entries for 2.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Ancillary TOC entries for \textbf{2.}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Ancillary TOC entries for \textbf{2.}}

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

which produces the TOC:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I modify the MWE so as to produce a TOC with only the (two) sections displayed and the (five) subsections suppressed? I compile the document code with `lualatex`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the counter `tocdepth` to control the level appearing in the ToC. When `tocdepth=1`  only chapters and sections will appear.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %Only sections and chapters in ToC<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \LARGE
    
    Some words.
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{\bf 1.} The main part of the TOC entries for 1.}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Ancillary TOC entries for \textbf{1.}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Ancillary TOC entries for \textbf{1.}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Ancillary TOC entries for \textbf{1.}}
    
    \newpage
    Some more words.
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{\bf 2.} The main part of the TOC entries for 2.}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Ancillary TOC entries for \textbf{2.}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Ancillary TOC entries for \textbf{2.}}
    
    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Many thanks @Simon Dispa